# Find a point on scaled image

Tags: android, imageview

I have a image with high resolution shown in an image view on a tablet. In order to fit the image, android scales it down to available width & height. I want to show a marker on this image. I have coordinates of marker for original high resolution image. How do I translate them for new scaled down image?

I tried following code but doesn't work well with images of different sizes.

```
float scaleFactor = Math.min((float)(newHeight*1.0/originalHeight), (float)(newWidth*1.0/originalWidth));
float xCoordinate = Float.parseFloat(marker.getXCoordinate()) * scaleFactor;
float yCoordinate = Float.parseFloat(marker.getYCoordinate()) * scaleFactor;
```

Edit:

I am using the scaling of type FIT_CENTER for showing image in imageview.
I have also tried with different scaling factors for height & width but didn't work out well.

Comment: How are you scaling down the image? Is it centerCrop? fitXY?

Comment: Did you try using separate scale factors for the height and width? It could be that the scaling is not the same...